# How to hide partial portion of subsection heading in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

Let us consider the following scenario.

If I write like the following, it will appear in table of contents as "Hai Hello".

```
      \subsection{Hai Hello}
```

But I want to hide "Hello" in table of contents. The table of contents have to show only "Hai".

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `\subsection[Hai]{Hai Hello}` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Basically any documentclass I've used so far has `sectioning` commands such as `\section`, `\subsection` etc. which provide an optional argument which is meant for the title designed for the ToC, whereas the mandatory is used in the document text as heading.

This was introduced to limit the length of ToC entries, but it can be used to *abbreviate* headings for the ToC as well.

An automatic 'shortening' requires more work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section[Super]{Super section}
\subsection[Hai]{Hai Hello}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the ams document classes have a different mechanism; by default, the *full* title goes into the toc, and the short version is used only for running heads. (but there *is* a documented workaround.)  so it's really important to read the relevant documentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I've never used `ams` classes. I admit, that the O.P. was not very clear about his class

Comment: you're probably entirely safe with what you answered.  there aren't all that many people in this forum who *do* use the ams classes, and those who do usually say so.  just being my usual nit-pickerly self.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I am aware that the `ams` class do something (well, *strange*) regarding the ToC, perhaps I'll add another *solution* too, but not right now.

Comment: i gave the gory details about tocs and `amsbook` in my answer to [How to hide a footnote in a section title from the table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123763/579).  a pointer to that might be sufficient.