# remove footnote from the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there any way to remove the footnote hyperlink from the table of contents ?

My MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test \protect \footnote{test of footnote}}
\section{Section One }
\section{Section two}
\chapter{Test \protect \footnote{test of footnote}}
\section{another section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\chapter[Test]{Test \protect \footnote{test of footnote}}` ?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123758/92620 ?

Comment: Thank you for you help, there's no automatic command !