# Removing the extra information at a definition? (thmtools&amsthm)

Tags: amsthm, thmtools

I noticed that the list of theorems doesn't make much sense for definitions because what I get basically is just `1.5 Def` etc. which doesn't convey any information. Hence I added the extra information as shown below so that I'd get `1.5 Def (Vector Space)` in the list of theorems which helps me a lot actually. However it makes the text a bit less legible because now instead of `Def. 1.5`  I get `Def. 1.5 (Vector Space)` as expected. Is there a way to remove this additional information in the actual text but have it shown in the list of theorems?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={definition}]
\begin{definition}[Vector Space]
....
\end{defintion}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `math.sty`? Your own collection of math macros?

Comment: Yes you can say that. In `math.sty` there is stuff like `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: i suggest defining and using a command `\SkipTocEntry` comparable to what's explained in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24798/579. that would permit you to omit the optional argument to `definition`, and insert it only for the toc.

Comment: @gonenc: 'hidden' user-defined package files are in general not useful for users willing to help you ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I wasn't trying to hide it :) I was just too lazy to type it out but in any case I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @gonenc Do you plan having theorems *with* the optional argument to be printed along with the label?

Comment: @egreg I have theorems with additional arguments, apart from the definitions, whose additional arguments are quasi optional.

Comment: @gonenc Please explain whether your list of theorems should include also the other theorems and in that case what you expect the output is.

Comment: @egreg The list that I'm making should only include the definitions. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to modify the definition of `\ll@definition`, but actually some more work is needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[
  style=definition,
  name=Definition,
]{innerdefinition}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{definition}[1][]
 {\def\gonenc@thmt@shortoptarg{#1}\innerdefinition}
 {\endinnerdefinition}
\def\ll@innerdefinition{%
  \protect\numberline{\csname the\thmt@envname\endcsname}%
    \thmt@thmname
  \ifx\@empty\gonenc@thmt@shortoptarg
  \else
    \ (\gonenc@thmt@shortoptarg)%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftheorems[ignoreall,show={innerdefinition}]

\begin{definition}[Vector Space]
You know what a \emph{vector space} is, don't you?
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to work flawlessly :)